# Make each <i> element in the center of the div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a draggable, droppable image in a grid. Here each box in the grid is a div and each icon is an  element. I want each icon element in the center of each box in the grid. But failed to do so. Please Help me out. I know I am missing something very common , but cant get the idea right now.Here is my code.

```js
function makeDraggable() {
        $(".far").draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        })
        $(".far").droppable({
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
                $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);
                makeDraggable();
            }

        })
    }
function randomColor(colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "white", "orange"]){
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
};
function randomIcons(){
  var icon = ["far fa-angry","far fa-address-card","far fa-address-book","far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down","far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"];
  return icon[Math.floor(Math.random() * icon.length)];
    //return icon
};
function generateGrid() {
  x = parseInt(document.getElementById('xaxis').value)
  y = parseInt(document.getElementById('yaxis').value)
  colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "white", "orange"]
  container = document.createElement("div");
  container.id = "main";
  container.className = "container";
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";
    row.id = "row" + i;
    for (let j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      box = document.createElement("div");
      box.className = "box";
      box.style.backgroundColor = randomColor(colors);
      row.appendChild(box);
      icons = document.createElement("i")
      icons.className = randomIcons()
      
      box.appendChild(icons);
    }
    container.appendChild(row);
  }
  let app = document.getElementById("app");
  app.appendChild(container);
  makeDraggable();
};
function resetUI(){
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: cursive;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  
}

html{
 background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1435752/pexels-photo-1435752.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260');  
 
}

#full1{
  margin: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  /* background-color: whitesmoke; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Notice how this gets configured before we load Font Awesome
  window.FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: false }
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.js" integrity="sha512-AsoAG+OFcSvtqlspW166UTUYg7F4GEu0yNhzTIRfOGysIQA8Dqk1WZwyoN4eX6mX4DaSk703Q1iM0M47rw25Kw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <div id="full1">
  <form style="text-align: center;">Draggable Grid<br><br><br>
    <label for="fname">Boxes on X axis:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Max value < 8" id="xaxis"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Boxes on Y axis:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Max value < 5" id="yaxis"><br><br>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="generateGrid()" value="Submit">
    <input type="button" onclick="resetUI()" value="Clear">
  </form>
  <div id="app" style="position:fixed;
  top: 36%;
  left: 30%; "></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex and align and justify element center.

```
.box{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `flex` display properties for each created `box` element you can align the icon to the center with `align-items` and `justify-content`

```js
function makeDraggable() {
        $(".far").draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        })
        $(".far").droppable({
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
                $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);
                makeDraggable();
            }

        })
    }
function randomColor(colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "white", "orange"]){
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
};
function randomIcons(){
  var icon = ["far fa-angry","far fa-address-card","far fa-address-book","far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down","far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"];
  return icon[Math.floor(Math.random() * icon.length)];
    //return icon
};
function generateGrid() {
  x = parseInt(document.getElementById('xaxis').value)
  y = parseInt(document.getElementById('yaxis').value)
  colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "white", "orange"]
  
  container = document.createElement("div");
  container.id = "main";
  container.className = "container";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";
    row.id = "row" + i;
    for (let j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      box = document.createElement("div");
      box.className = "box";
      box.style.backgroundColor = randomColor(colors);
      row.appendChild(box);
      icons = document.createElement("i")
      icons.className = randomIcons()
      
      box.appendChild(icons);
    }
    container.appendChild(row);
  }
  let app = document.getElementById("app");
  app.appendChild(container);
  makeDraggable();
};
function resetUI(){
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: cursive;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  
  /* set flex properties here to align icon to centre of div */
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}




html{
 background-image: url('//images.pexels.com/photos/1435752/pexels-photo-1435752.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260');  
 
}

#full1{
  margin: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  /* background-color: whitesmoke; */
}
```

```html
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script>
  window.FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: false }
</script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.js' integrity='sha512-AsoAG+OFcSvtqlspW166UTUYg7F4GEu0yNhzTIRfOGysIQA8Dqk1WZwyoN4eX6mX4DaSk703Q1iM0M47rw25Kw==' crossorigin='anonymous' referrerpolicy='no-referrer'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css' integrity='sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==' crossorigin='anonymous' referrerpolicy='no-referrer' />


  <div id='full1'>
    <form style='text-align: center;'>Draggable Grid<br><br><br>
      <label for='fname'>Boxes on X axis:</label>
      <input type='text' placeholder='Max value < 8' id='xaxis'><br><br>
      <label for='lname'>Boxes on Y axis:</label>
      <input type='text' placeholder='Max value < 5' id='yaxis'><br><br>
      <input type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='generateGrid()' value='Submit'>
      <input type='button' onclick='resetUI()' value='Clear'>
    </form>
    
    <div id='app' style='position:fixed; top: 36%; left: 30%; '></div>
  </div>
```